# Way to store sequence in a Perl script

Tags: perl

What is the Best way to store sequence in a text file or some other way by Perl script. When I run the script for first time, I want the sequence to be 1 and for second time 2. I should also take care of contention when more than one Perl process access the file.

```
my $seqfile = "f";
my $fh = FileHandle->new($seqfile, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
my $seq = $fh->getline;
$seq = 0 unless($seq);
$seq = $seq + 1;
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
```

How to write the `$seq` back without losing the lock on the file?

Comment: "Sequence" is usually longer than one number.

Comment: Basically you want to lock a file (flock), open it (open), read a number from it, increment the number, write it back to the file, close it and release the lock.

Comment: @marderh Thanks, the way I thought.

Comment: I think you open the file before you call `flock` since you need to pass an filehandle to `flock`.

Comment: use some of `DBM` storages with locking feature, ie. http://search.cpan.org/~rkinyon/DBM-Deep-2.0009/lib/DBM/Deep.pod#LOCKING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
my $seqfile = "f";
my $fh = FileHandle->new($seqfile, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die; # alternatively do loop retrying...
my $seq = $fh->getline;
$seq = 0 unless($seq);
$seq = $seq + 1;
seek ($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
print $fh $seq;
close ($fh);
```

Note that close($fh) will take care of flushing buffered data to file as well as releasing lock.